# Android Widget from SD Card

Tags: android, android-widget, app2sd

Hey,
I just added a Widget to my Android App but when I now move my App to SD the Widget disappears and is not listet any more. Is there any trick so that I can still use a Widget oder twi I have to write a second "Widget App" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets are explicitly disabled in SD installed applications:
[Android issue tracking that](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11283).

Answer (score 3):

Widgets are not supported for apps installed on SD with the current sdks. You can either not support App2SD or write a second widget app. Depends on your needs.